# Normal Distribution (using calculator)

Tags: self-study

I know this is more a calculator question than statistics, but here it goes. My statistics professor is wanting us to rely on our calculators, but I'm having trouble with my NSpire CAS. Here's an example:

According to a report by Scarborough Research, the average monthly household cellular phone bill is 73 dollars. Suppose monthly household cell phone bills are normally distributed with a standard deviation of 11.35 dollars.

What is the probability that a randomly selected monthly cell phone bill is between 80 dollars and 90 dollars?

The answer, in my book, is .2008, but I'm getting .20161 on my Nspire (using the normCdf function). I know that isn't that much of a difference in answers, but my online homework is picky, not to mention, I know my professor might have questions with similar multiple choices on our exam.

Comment: This isn't really a calculator question as far as I can see; it's a question of whether you did the problem correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers you give do result in 0.20161

So if the numbers in your question were not prematurely rounded off, you're correct.

But (for example) if the actual mean in the original question had been 72.955, but you had rounded that to 73 before posting, then the correct answer (using the original value) would be 0.2008

(Alternatively, that amount of difference - getting 0.2008 when the correct answer is 0.2016 - might sometimes occur when using tables rather than a calculator)

Comment: That makes sense! When the question has all whole numbers, I get the exact answer as I should. However, for this question, I entered the lower/upper bound, mean, and standard deviation exactly as it showed in the problem.